# Django display search results in template

Tags: django, templates, search, display

im quite new to Django and i want to display the search results in my search.html template but i missed the paths somehow...
I use a context processor to display the searchbox together with a category selector globally. So the query against the database is a set of Catagorie and keyword.

1. Not sure if i implement it the right way.
2. No idea how to display the results in my Template.
3. What to do with the catagoerie in the view.py ?

**base.py**

```
<div class="globalsearch">
        <form id="searchform" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <label for="{{ categorysearch_form.category.id_for_label }}">In category: </label> {{ categorysearch_form.category }}
            <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search for ...">
            <button class="searchbutton" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**views.py**

```
class globalsearch(ListView):

    model = Post
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Post.objects.published()

        keywords = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if keywords:
            query = SearchQuery(keywords)
            title_vector = SearchVector('title', weight='A')
            content_vector = SearchVector('content', weight='B')
            tag_vector = SearchVector('tag', weight='C')
            vectors = title_vector + content_vector + tag_vector
            qs = qs.annotate(search=vectors).filter(search=query)
            qs = qs.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vectors, query)).order_by('-rank')

        return qs
```

in the end a want to display the results the same way as i display it on my 
**post_list.html:**

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
            <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>Published by: {{ post.author }}</a><br>
                <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>Category: {{ post.category }}</a><br>
                <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div>
        <span>
         {% if posts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; First <a> |</a></a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if posts.has_next %}
            <span> Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">Next<a> |</a></a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
       </span>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**search.html**

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
            <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>Published by: {{ post.author }}</a><br>
                <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>Category: {{ post.category }}</a><br>
                <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) adds your queryset to the context as `object_list` so just do a `{% for obj in object_list %}` to iterate over that in your `post_list.html`

Your template would look something like;

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
            <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>Published by: {{ post.author }}</a><br>
                <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>Category: {{ post.category }}</a><br>
                <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% if is_paginated %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

You could change the context variable name by defining `context_object_name` in your view. e.g. `context_object_name = 'posts'`

Comment: Im still getting an empty response :(
can you maybe have a quick look: https://github.com/rsmvdl/quickblog/tree/master/quickblog

Comment: The template on there is still doing `{% for post in posts %}` without changing the context variable name. Print/debug the `get_queryset` to ensure `qs` contains something?

Comment: I've implemented all the changes but still only get the footer and the header :( The actual content of the view/results is missing.

Comment: @Venom yeah, but in you view, does your queryset actually return anything from the database?

Comment: @ markwalker_ 1 currently i dont get back anything at all... simply white page with header and footer.

Comment: @Venom ignore the rendered page. That can't work if the queryset doesn't contain anything, so go to the root of the problem, in `get_queryset()` you have `return qs` so you need to debug that to check if `qs` contains any objects. If your query doesn't get anything from the data, then your for loop has nothing to loop over.

Comment: Any idea how i can accomplish that in pycharm? Im quite new to this whole thing ... thanks :)

Comment: @Venom if you're using pycharm it's easy. Just set a breakpoint on the line `return qs` and then use the debug runserver and when your view is called, execution should stop on your breakpoint so you can evaluate the queryset. This should explain things; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFuaU3Sl4-c

Comment: @ markwalker_ : I've got back this stuff: https://pastebin.com/PkW5LqLY

Comment: @Venom That `tail_len: 15` suggests you've got 15 objects to display. Either your parent template isn't working with your `content` block properly or the content of your for loop isn't correct to display your posts. Just put `{{ post }}`` inside `{% for post in object_list }}` to see if the post will render at all. If that doesn't help, read the page source to see if the correct markup is in there.

Comment: No it does not render it all and it also seems that "q" dont get passed to the view... No idea why